# Copy some information of logfile with specific date

Tags: batch, batch-file

I want to copy some information from a log file of PC in my company for a specific date, the remote PC has a Windows account with a password. I try to share the folder to have access to this one but I don't get it, so I want to use the XCOPY - it's simple and work for me. Just one think I want to access to the information in the logfile to copy just the date that I want.

For example, the log file contains all the log of this month, but I want just the last 3 days from `09-04-2021 to 12-04-2021`.

```
xcopy C:\Sut\Stat\03-2021.log \\myserver\backup$\Logfiles\week3.log
```

The remote PC name : c022457

Logfile examples:

[image: logfile example in attached photos]

[image: logfile example in attached photos]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `findstr`. E.g.

```
findstr /rc:"\<9. Apr 21\>" ^
/rc:"\<10. Apr 21\>" ^
/rc:"\<11. Apr 21\>" ^
/rc:"\<12. Apr 21\>" ^
C:\Sut\Stat\04-2021.log > \\myserver\backup$\Logfiles\week3.log
```

This will find logs from `9. Apr 21` to `12. Apr 21` and save output to the file `\\myserver\backup$\Logfiles\week3.log`

Comment: Hello @Aenfa I try this one as a batch file but doesn't work for me